# SQlite: failure during a script creating tables doesn't rollback

Tags: sqlite

I have this simple script in a file named `test.sql`:

```
begin;
create table t1 (id integer);
create table t2; --error here
commit;
```

The script has an obvious error in line 3. I call this script with the following command line:

```
sqlite3.exe test.db ".read test.sql"
```

As expected, the executable fails blaming line 3 for a syntax error. However, the database `test.db` is created and contains table `t1`, despite the presence of the opening `begin`.

Is this the expected behavior? Shouldn't the transation be rolled back? How to ensure that tables are commited only when creation succeeded for all of them?

Comment: You can try with `begin exclusive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the [command-line shell](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) treats all statements as if they were entered interactively.

To stop when an error occurs, use `.bail on`.

Comment: Thanks. I also note that my original command line now leaves an opened journal file, while calling `sqlite3.exe test.db < test.sql` instead cleans up the mess more nicely.